# Problems converting deepLearning4j array to ONNX Tensor

Tags: java, tensorflow, onnx, deeplearning4j, onnxruntime

I'm currently reading an image with deepLearning4j and trying to pass it to ONNX is giving me problems.

```java
INDArray ndArray =  loader.asMatrix(mat3).permute(0,2,3,1);

OnnxTensor tensor = OnnxTensor.createTensor(env, ndArray.data().asNioFloat(), ndArray.shape());
```

The problems is that they are not the same. The INDArray is like this:

```
[[[[  103.0000   41.0000  155.0000] 
   [  103.0000   42.0000  154.0000] 
   [  102.0000   44.0000  153.0000] 
   [  101.0000   45.0000  152.0000] 
   [  101.0000   45.0000  152.0000] 
   .....
```

And the ONNX tensor is like this:

```
[103.0, 103.0, 102.0]
[101.0, 101.0, 101.0]
[101.0, 101.0, 101.0]
[101.0, 101.0, 101.0]
[101.0, 101.0, 101.0]
```

The overall shape I think is not the problem, that is how is printed but the columns of the NDArray are rows in ONNX

Answer (score 1):

You can check our nd4j-onnxruntime module for that. We don't directly use the normal bindings though. We use javacpp's onnxruntime. The concept should be similar though:

```
 Pointer inputTensorValuesPtr = ndArray.data().pointer();
        Pointer inputTensorValues = inputTensorValuesPtr;
        long sizeInBytes = ndArray.length() * ndArray.data().getElementSize();

        /**
         *   static Value CreateTensor(const OrtMemoryInfo* info, void* p_data, size_t p_data_byte_count, const int64_t* shape, size_t shape_len,
         *                             ONNXTensorElementDataType type)
         */
        LongPointer dims = new LongPointer(ndArray.shape());
        Value ret =  Value.CreateTensor(
                memoryInfo.asOrtMemoryInfo(),
                inputTensorValues,
                sizeInBytes,
                dims,
                ndArray.rank(),
                onnxTypeForDataType(ndArray.dataType()));
```

Note that using NIOfloat and other similar concepts creates unnecessary overhead. Please consider using our interop module if possible.

You can see above with our own interop the data should just work as is.

I don't have much experience with the original onnxruntime bindings but I would check 2 points:

1. How the data's being converted
2. The ordering of the data. If your data is in f ordering you might have issues. If ordering of the data is the issue you can do ndarray.dup('c') and that should fix your issue. That again incurs overhead twice though. Once for reordering the data and another for converting the data to NIO.